# Turn string to object within _.each

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I'm using underscore in an Angular controller and attempting to turn a string into an object with several properties.

```
vm.availableGames = _.each(availableGames, function(game) {
  game.name = game;
  if (_.contains(user.allowed_games.games, game)) {
    game.allowed = true;
  } else {
    game.allowed = false;
  }
});
```

`availableGames` is an array of strings of available games
`allowed_games` is also an array of strings of allowed games

My aim is to create an array of objects (`vm.availableGames`) which contains all available games. Each of these objects will have a name property (the original string) and an allowed property (a boolean).

The above code results in a `Cannot assign to read only property...` error. How would I go about accomplishing what I'm aiming for without running into this error?

Comment: `_.each` doesn't return anything. You can use `_.map` instead (and `return game;` after your if/else block)

Comment: @Matt, I still encounter the same error because I'm still attempting to assign properties (`name`, `allowed`) to a string `game`. However, if I setup a new empty object (`var gm = {}`) and then do `gm.name = game` it works. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work:

```
vm.availableGames = _.map(availableGames, function(game) {
  return {
    name: game,
    allowed: _.contains(user.allowed_games, game)
  };
});
```

and without underscore:

```
vm.availableGames = availableGames.map(function(game) {
  return {
    name: game,
    allowed: (user.allowed_games.indexOf(game) !== -1)
  };
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not underscore, but will this work?

```
vm.availableGames = [];

for( game in availableGames ) {
    if( allowed_games.indexOf(game) !== -1 )
        vm.availableGames.push({ allowed: true, name: availableGames[game] });
    else
        vm.availableGames.push({ allowed: false, name: availableGames[game] });
}
for( game in allowed_games ) {
    if( availableGames.indexOf(allowed_games[game]) !== -1 )
        vm.availableGames.push({ allowed: true, name: allowed_games[game] });
}
```

EDIT: Answer using forEach...

NOTE: This only works if everything in allowed_games is also in availableGames.

```
availableGames.forEach(function( game ) {
    vm.availableGames.push({ allowed: allowed_games.indexOf(game) !== -1, name: game });
});
```

Comment: This answer assumes ES6, doesn't use strict equality tests, and doesn't use braces for if statements? _sigh_

Comment: Sorry, where am I assuming ES6? I kind of wrote the second part in a rush.

Comment: `for..of` in the first part of the answer.

Comment: Oh, I'm just to assumed to all major browsers supporting it that I forgot it was ES6. Should be an easy fix

Comment: ~You just need to remove that first part of the answer, because `for..in` needs a [`hasOwnProperty`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/684692) check anyway.~ Actually, for arrays, that doesn't matter I guess. Also that condition can be inlined into the `allowed` boolean (see my edit on the second part).

Comment: @Matt no, in modern code `for .. in` does _not_ need a `hasOwnProperty` check.  However you shouldn't use `for .. in` on arrays anyway.

Comment: I guess I was right to get the downvote... If people want to use bloated frameworks that replace vanilla JavaScript with slow methods, that's their choice and they'll probably not want to compromise their beliefs